# Why is for loop iterating over (seemingly) empty list?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer, I decided to write a simple program getting prime factors out of a number and then printing them, but I'm having trouble in printing the final result. Here's the code:

```
n = int(raw_input("Number?: "))
m = n
k = 2
czynniki = []       

while(m != 1):
    if m%k == 0:
        czynniki.append(k)
        print m, "\t", '|', k
        m = m/k
    else:
        k+=1
print m

print n, ' = ',
for czynnik in czynniki:
    if czynniki.count(czynnik)>1:
        print czynnik, '^', czynniki.count(czynnik), ' *',
        czynniki = filter(lambda x: x!=czynnik, czynniki)
    else:
        print czynnik, ' *',
```

Everything is okay until the very end. For example I'd like it to print "1025 = 5^2 * 41" when 1025 is inputed, but instead it will print "1025 = 5^2 * 5 * 41", as if filter function had no impact at all. Where's the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting the `for` loop over the list that is stored in `czynniki`, that you're later changing what `czynniki` references (a totally new list) does not change which list the `for` loops over. It's not safe to change the actual list a loop is running over either, so you can't really do it like this either way.

You may want to rewrite the loop something like this, just skip the duplicate values instead and not try to change the loop while running;

```
var lastvalue = -1;
for czynnik in czynniki:
    if lastvalue == czynnik:
        continue
    if czynniki.count(czynnik)>1:
        print czynnik, '^', czynniki.count(czynnik), ' *',
        lastvalue = czynnik
    else:
        print czynnik, ' *',
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are modifying the list `czynniki` while iterating over it. Try this instead:

```
print n, ' = ',
for czynnik in sorted(set(czynniki)):
    if czynniki.count(czynnik)>1:
        print czynnik, '^', czynniki.count(czynnik), '*',
    else:
        print czynnik, '*',
```

Here you iterate over a separate list of only unique items of your list `czynniki`. This is achieved by casting the list to a set (an unsorted list of unique items) and then back to a sorted list.

If you want to get rid of that surplus `*` at the end, you could try this:

```
result_list = []
for czynnik in sorted(set(czynniki)):
    if czynniki.count(czynnik)>1:
        result_list.append(str(czynnik) + '^' + str(czynniki.count(czynnik)))
    else:
        result_list.append(str(czynnik))
print n, '=', ' * '.join(result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use continue keyword if you want to skip some item in a loop instead of filtering collection you trying to go over.

Comment: What do you mean? I use filter function to remove all instances of a given value from the list, because they've already been printed (for example if three fives are on the list I want the program to print "5^3" and then remove all three from the list.

Comment: You can't change the collection your for is operating on, if you don't interested in duplicates is better to remove them before you started printing , you can acomplish this by converting your list to set

Comment: Okay, I got it, Thanks for help :)